# Can't import object detection imageai (python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imageai

I installed imageai,tensorflow,keras in python with pip

i typed this code

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
```

it shows this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.advanced_activations'
```

module versions
imageai - 2.0.2
keras - 2.90
tensorflow - 2.9.1

im running on windows 10 pro

Comment: You need to update your version of `imageai`. It's from 3 years ago. `pip install -U imageai`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update version of **imageai** to new versions.
[try this](https://pypi.org/project/imageai/2.1.6/)

Answer (score 0):

As `imageai` now uses `Pytorch` in backend, you must install a few library dependencies before installing `imageai`. Please refer to this [link](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the same.

```
pip install cython pillow>=7.0.0 numpy>=1.18.1 opencv-python>=4.1.2 torch>=1.9.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu torchvision>=0.10.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu pytest==7.1.3 tqdm==4.64.1 scipy>=1.7.3 matplotlib>=3.4.3 mock==4.0.3

pip install imageai --upgrade
```

Import the Object detection api from `imageai`

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.